# Django javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In a Django app, where should I put my javascript/jquery scripts?

Comment: I believe this may be helpful: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In with your other static media. See here for more info:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about using that then? Trying to follow http://blog.dpeepul.com/tag/django-voting/ - Step 4. If I put this code in my media folder, how would I include it?

Comment: Make sure you're serving it properly, according to the link, and then access it at yoururl/yourmedia/, or whatever you've configured it to, perhaps localhost:8000/media/.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237418/serving-static-media-during-django-development-why-not-media-root) provides more information

Answer (score 2):

You have defined paths for **media** and **static** into the settings.py:

```
import os.path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media'))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'))
```

- Used **BASE_DIR** to calculate the path to the settings.py file
- Used **BASE_DIR** to generate the **MEDIA_ROOT** and **STATIC_ROOT** paths to the previous path of settings

Following that structure the path structure should be:

```
-yourApp
----manage.py
----media
----static
----yourApp
--------settings.py
--------models.py
```

[Django: How to manage static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)