# Accessing "Media" files in Django

Tags: django

I'd like to love Django, but this business of static and media files in development environments is driving me nuts. Please rescue me from my stupidity.

I'm on my development machine. I have folder `media` in the root of my project directory.

In `settings.py` I have: `MEDIA_ROOT = ''` and `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`.

In `urls.py` I have:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
            'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
    )
```

But the only way I can get media files is by referencing `/media/media/` e.g. 
`<img  src="/media/media/image.png" />`.

I expect (and want)
`<img  src="/media/image.png" />`

Can anyone tell me what is happening here, and give me a simple recipe for setting up media file handling?

Thank you very much.

---

@Timmy O'Mahony - thanks! epic post, and very clear. But it leaves a couple of questions:

(1) I have to use `/media/` and `/static/`, not `media/` and `static/` as `MEDIA_URL` and and `STATIC_URL` - am I missing something?

(2) If `collectstatic` hoses `/static/`, where do you put site level CSS e.g. the site's CSS files? Not in `/static/`, evidently.

(3) I put them in a directory '_' off the project root and set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to point to it - and that seems to be where the development server gets its static files, despite the `urlpatterns` directive. If THAT is wrong, where do you put site level CSS during development, and what is the workflow around `collectstatic` when you modify them - do you have to edit them one place, and collect them someplace else after every edit?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Why have you made the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting blank? It needs to be the path to your media directory. Since, as you say, your media is in a subdirectory called `media`, you should put that in `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: Specifically, it should be `MEDIA_ROOT = "media/"`

Comment: I prefer using absolute paths to avoid problems. I use a small wrapper for this in my settings.py:

`import os.path`

`ABSOLUTE_PATH = lambda x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), x)`

`MEDIA_ROOT = ABSOLUTE_PATH('media/')`

Answer (score 187):

**Folder Setup:**

Your project root should be something like:

```
/app1
/app2
/media
/static
/templates
urls.py
settings.py
manage.py
```

The **media** folder is supposed to hold things like images, downloads and other material that might be uploaded during normal use of the website (i.e. after development is finished)

The **static** folder is supposed to hold all the CSS/JS and other material that is a part of the development of the site

---

**Settings.py:**

**MEDIA_ROOT** is the absolute server path to the static folder mentioned above. That means it should be something like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/User/Bob/Sites/MySite/Project_root/media/"
```

**MEDIA_URL** is the relative browser URL you should access your media files from when you are looking at the site. It should be (usually)

```
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
```

which means all material can be viewed at http://example.com/media/

Similarly, **STATIC_ROOT** should be something like

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/User/Bob/Sites/MySite/Project_root/static/"
```

and **STATIC_URL** be

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

---

**Serving the files:**

Now that you have told django where these folders should be, and the correct URLs to access them, you need to serve all requests to the folders correctly.

Usually when you are in production, you want the webserver to take care of serving your static files and media files.

If you are developing though, you can just get the django development server to serve them for you.

To do this, you tell it to route all request that come in to http://example.com/media to your MEDIA_ROOT and all requests that come in to http://example.com/static to your STATIC_ROOT.

To do this, you add some URLS to URLS.py like you have:

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
)
```

---

**Extra**:

If you have multiple apps, each with their own CSS and JS files, you mightn't want to throw them into one single /static/ folder. It might be useful to put them in subfolders of the apps they belong to:

```
/app1/static/ # Specific static folder
/app2/static/
/media/
/static/ # Root static folder
```

Now, your webserver/development server is only looking for static files where you told it to look (i.e. the root static folder) so you need to collect all the files in the subfolders and copy them to the root static folder. You could do this by hand, but django provides a command to do this for you (this is the whole point of the static app)

```
./manage collectstatic
```

Comment: Thanks man, I completely forgot about the 'static serve' of the development serve, wondering why the hell my files weren't served. If I could, I would upvote your post a lot more ;)

Comment: [I've tidied this answer up and turned it into a blog post](http://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/)

Comment: Great answer and post. Something you might want to add to your blog-post, though, would be adding the [media context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-media) explicitly, as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31925082) mentions. Otherwise, as I found out the hard way, `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ evt_pic }}">` won't be defined in templates. As of 1.8+, it's not explicitly added.

Comment: Having said that the `media context_processor` is needed, I was just reading the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31925244/78409) to the same question, and interestingly, ImageFields also provide a URL, so actually the context_processor and MEDIA_URL are _not_ needed: `src="{{artist.artist_image.url}}`

Comment: The blog post is perhaps the most comprehensive and understandable writeup on Django static files that I have seen so far. Do you also want to turn the comments on on the blog post to get a discussion going?

Comment: Django introduced a more concise way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38446584/2800876

Answer (score 18):

I followed timmy procedure but I got an error that No module name `django.views`. When I use `import django.views` in my virtualenv everything works fine i.e It's not an issue with the import of library.

However, I was able to solve this problem by following this procedure in my main urls file

```
from django.conf.urls.static import  static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem so I added these lines

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^cadmin/', include('cadmin.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in `urls.py` in the Django project configuration directory. more information :https://overiq.com/django/1.10/handling-media-files-in-django/

Answer (score 4):

In your **settings.py**, make sure you add

> django.core.context_processors.media

in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS.Otherwise the MEDIA_ROOT won't work when you use it in the templates.

Comment: that's not needed, atleast as of django 1.9.4

Answer (score 3):

I am using Django 1.10. And my media folder is 'uploads'
This is the configuration in my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

And in the template I put the name o my MEDIA_URL before de object.name instead object.url like this:

```
    <img src="uploads/{{ imagen_identificativa.name }} " alt="{{imagen_identificativa}}">
```

And it works for me.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For Django version 3 I used the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
    ]
```

my settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

here is a documentation link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/
In case you are using Django REST with some dev server don't forget to update your dev proxy settings to redirect `/media` to Django backend

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative:

Set your media configs something like this inside 'settings.py':

```
#Set media path
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Lets say I have a modal called person with image filed like below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos')
```

Now here upload_to path we are taking about is inside the MEDIA_ROOT folder. In my case a media folder will be created inside which photos folder will be created and our media here will be dumped.

So now in my template I do something like this:

```
<img src="{{ person.photo.url}} />
```

So in short, you got a field, use it like this:

```
src ={{ object.field.url}}
```

Hope that helps! Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I spent 1/2 day trying to find THE solution. The magic bullet was using src = {{ object.field.url }}
Everything seemed to be set up correctly. I used the Admin feature to create the folder in the root - media\images\aaa.jpg

What I had:

setting.py

```
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT )
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to="images/")
```

html file

```
<img src={{quiz.image}} alt="no image found">
```

Changing the above to

```
<img src={{quiz.image.url}} alt="no image found">
```

displayed the image!!