# How to render file in django template

Tags: python, django, file

PLease I am trying to render django file in the template, the problem is that , I am taking audio, video and images as input and I don't know how to render them in my html template. Whether I will use  tag or  tag or  tag.

Comment: enable media folder in your project,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing Video with Django and html5 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953301/playing-video-with-django-and-html5-tag)