# How do we seek/backward video file that stored in Django backend?

Tags: python, django, video, websocket

I have a video file that plays with HTML in frontend, but I can't seek/forward/backward the video.

How do I implement this feature ? Any web technologies in any language will be welcomed.

I am thinking about web sockets in python and socket.io in JS.

Comment: this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394864/11282077

Comment: _"I have a video file that plays with HTML in frontend"_ Where is the demo link to see the problem in action and advise?