# Django: MEDIA_URL not set in template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've read a lot of question and article but can't find what I'm missing.

Here is my conf :

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static').replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('home.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^artist/', include('artists.urls')),
    url(r'photo/', include('photo.urls'))
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Whatever, my media are served, cause when I go to http://localhost:8000/media/path/to/image.jpg, i have my image.

But when in template I go like this :

```
<img class="avatar secondary-content" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{artist.artist_image}}">
```

I only  have the image path. When I change in html `{{MEDIA_URL}}` by '/media/', it works.

So it seems my `MEDIA_URL` is not set in template and as far as I've searched, I can't see what I missed.

I'm on django 1.8.2. If you need any informations, just ask me.

Comment: for post processed thumbnails the Url property is not callable. Prepending MEDIA_URL is not working for me also as stated by the question above. In such cases we need MEDIA_URL in template also.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`models.ImageField` has a property called `url` which gives you the browsable path of your image.

You should be using `artist.artist_image.url` instead of prepending `MEDIA_URL` to your image name manually:

```
<img class="avatar secondary-content" src="{{artist.artist_image.url}}" />
```

--

Make sure `artist_image` is not `None`, otherwise calling `.url` throws an exception.

Comment: Dude, that's perfect :).

Comment: for post processed thumbnails the Url property is not callable. Prepending MEDIA_URL is not working for me also as stated by the question above. In such cases we need MEDIA_URL in template also.

Answer (score 33):

You need to **define the [`django.template.context_processors.media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-media) template context processor** in your settings for `MEDIA_URL` variable to be present in the template context.

> If this processor is enabled, every `RequestContext` will contain a
>   variable `MEDIA_URL`, providing the value of the [`MEDIA_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_URL) setting.

Including this in your `settings` will include `MEDIA_URL` in the template context. It is **not included by default** in Django 1.8 settings. We need to **set it explicitly.**

```
context_processors = [
    ...
    'django.template.context_processors.media', # set this explicitly
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the other one fits better :).

Comment: @Bestasttung Other answer is only useful if you need to get full URL of an object. But if you want to access the media URL prefix, this answer is the solution.

Comment: This also worked for me. Now deciding which one to use between <img class="avatar secondary-content" src="{{artist.artist_image.url}}" /> or using your way of setting context_precossor with 'django.template.context_processors.media' and on template use {{ MEDIA_URL }}

Comment: best fit with the context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this in settings
so you can put {{MEDIA_URL}} in templates

```
context_processors = [
    'django.template.context_processors.media', # set this explicitly
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).