# Django admin: image saved but error occured when click

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I am ashamed to ask a question of that sort but I still can not solve my problem. I normally uploaded image in my media directory and can see image link in my admin but if I click on link I get:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/img/9.jpg
>   Using the URLconf defined in TeamStudy.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>   ^admin/
>   The current URL, photo/img/9.jpg, didn't match any of these.
>   my project structure:

```
src
static/
      photo/ 
           img/
```

settings:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'photo')
MEDIA_URL = '/photo/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

I suspect it perhaps quite simple and I miss something. Please point me.

Comment: why do you keep MEDIA_ROOT inside STATIC_ROOT ? when you can create another directory named 'media', at the same level as 'static' directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the media **MEDIA_ROOT** and  **MEDIA_URL** in your **urlpatterns**

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

check following links for more details

[Accessing "Media" files in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418072/accessing-media-files-in-django/6418281#6418281)

Django classifies user files in two types

1. Static files
2. Media files

[this link](https://timmyomahony.com/blog/static-vs-media-and-root-vs-path-in-django/) helps you understand the difference between them

Your issues deals with Media files.

> In future development, you may need to serve static files, to serve them you will need to add
>   **STATIC_ROOT** and **STATIC_URL** to the urlpatterns in a similar way that **MEDIA_ROOT** and **MEDIA_URL** are added

Comment: Welcome :)  Next time before you post such a question make sure you google properly!

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL's patterns:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

for more info [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Answer (score 0):

First point: don't put uploaded medias in you `static` directory - `static` is for static files that are part of your project (css, js etc) -, you want to use `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` for this.

wrt/ serving the static and media contents, it depends on the environment. On your local dev environment you want to use the `staticfile.views` to serve both static and medias as mentionned in the other answers, but *don't do this in production* : on a production server, you want to use your front web server to serve static (and media) contents.

Comment: Thank you for your useful tips!