# Page not found with POST request in the django's admin when i click any of the save button in Production environment

Tags: mysql, django, cpanel

At first, I tried installing MySQLclient via the terminal in a shared hosting platform only to get **GCC permission** denied, I contacted the admin pertaining the domain but to no assistance. I decided to use SQLite instead, everything worked fine, to my surprise no migrations were requested. Now when I wanted to add a product in the django admin page, when I click the save button I get an error that **page not found with request Post**. Everything works fine in development also when i request the same page while online in the admins page it loads fine. Kindly help

**Here is the gcc permission denied**
[Got this error when i tried pip install mysqlclient in cpanel terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PANcb.png)

**Here is the the product page at the admin**
[This is the product page while at the admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s8VA.png)

**Here is the error when i click any of the save buttons**
[This the error i get when i try to save the product by clicking any of the save buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeqEK.png)

Comment: This looks similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966813/django-admin-image-saved-but-error-occured-when-click

Comment: czarss thanks but it is not similar, is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498673/unable-pip-install-mysqlclient-execute-gcc-permission-denied

Comment: similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344774/django-admin-returns-404-on-post-200-on-get

Comment: I tried deleting the picture field and everything worked fine but now my site does not have pictures(an e-commerce site without pics!). How can i go about  so that i can retrive uploaded pictures from the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I escaped gcc permission denied by installing django 2.1 and followed this [Error loading MySQLdb Module 'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python) worked for me but now the problem is when i add a product with an imagefield i get page not found with request post

Comment: Followed https://pythonfusion.com/deploy-django-on-shared-hosting/#comment-75 on how to connect to mysql db without installing mysqlclient on a shared hosting platform