# Django imageField url on html

Tags: django, image, django-models

I've this hiearchy:

```
-mega_series
   -mega_series
   -series
      -models.py
      -views.py
      ...
   -manage.py
   -media
      -covers
   -static
```

The MEDIA_URL AND MEDIA_ROOT are the following:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/lechucico/Documents/mega_series/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

On the model I store the image like that:

```
class Serie (models.Model):
   serie_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers')
   serie_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The images once uploaded via admin site goes correctly to path: mega_series/media/covers/

And this is how I acces it via html:

```
<img src="{{serie.serie_cover.url}}" width="150" height="250" />
```

The result url that I got is the following:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/covers/juego_de_tronos.jpg

Why the image doesn't appear on the html?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py

Comment: try using `serie.serie_cover.url`

Comment: @Niyojan - Might want to put that as the answer, as it's the most likely cause

Comment: @Niyojan I don't have MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL. serie.serie_cover.url produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define `MEDIA_ROOT` as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

From Django officaal Docs:

```
urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418072/accessing-media-files-in-django).

Comment: I've edited the post with the instructions you gave me on the link. I think i'm close now but it stills not work. What i've done wrong this time?

Comment: well, the url seems legit to me and browser should load it. try to check the browser console log (`F12` key for google chrome) for loading errors. Also try with only `serie.serie.name`

Comment: I've tried: serie.serie.name, serie.serie.url, serie.serie.path and no one works. Terminal console shows the following when loading page: "GET /Users/lechucico/Documents/mega_series/media/covers/modern_family.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3218 , Not Found: /Users/lechucico/Documents/mega_series/media/covers/the_black_list.jpg.  It's so rare, because the image is on that path

Comment: I forgot to do add the static on the url.py (+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)). Why this is needed to be added?

Comment: thats a helper function so that django urls list also contains our media url and we can explore them.