# Site on localhost not displaying image

Tags: django, image

I am trying to get an image to appear using Django template.

In settings I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/workspace/mysite/uploaded_media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/mysite/media/'
```

The html is

```
<img source = "http://localhost:8000/mysite/media/blabla.jpg"></img>
```

I have an image file blabla.jpg in the folder uploaded_media

What am I missing here?

Edit: first problem was writing "source" instead of "src" in the  tag. doh. (attempting the answer below right now.)

Comment: what do you have in your settings.py / urls.py?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237418/serving-static-media-during-django-development-why-not-media-root

Comment: Not sure I understand. I settings.py I have the above stated settings as well as lots of other stuff. In urls.py, I don't have anything specific for the media. The page is rendered, it just doesn't show the image.

Comment: So look at the urls.py shown in the link I mentionned :)

Comment: Jeremy, oops, I didn't see the link ;) You are right, though, I was missing the pattern in urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in template

```
<img src="/media/blabla.jpg" />
```

Also put these lines of code inside your urls.py and set DEBUG to True

```
if settings.DEBUG:
  # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: look at my edit, the important part, the lines to add to your urls file

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick! (Also had to write "from django.conf import settings") But then does this only work in debug mode? Could I just add this pattern to my urlpatterns always, not just if settings.DEBUG?

Comment: When you're in production with a web server different from the django one, you'll serve this files statically through the web server by writing you desired roles. You may accept the answer if was useful to you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll worry about that when I get to production... It's working great for now.