# Django cant load static files

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage in Django and now I want to add some CSS (twitter bootstrap) to it. This is the first I am trying. I have carefully read the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) and did everything said there for the django development server to work. I am using development server with debug=True and django version 1.6.5. My settings.py looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 )
```

My files are under `/mysite/static/bootstrap/css` folder and in my template.html I have this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "boostrap/css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens, I see that the development server says:

```
 "GET /static/boostrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

which means it cannot find them. I even tried doing the settings without STATIC_ROOT, doing this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
)
```

but then the development server returns:

```
"GET /static/boostrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1682
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a path to your `urls.py` for those static files to be found (something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237418/serving-static-media-during-django-development-why-not-media-root)?

Comment: No, docs says nothing about this.

Comment: Huh, I've been doing it like this for awhile now (didn't realize it was supposed to serve this view automagically; now I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve

Answer (score 3):

You did everything right, the issue here is a simple typo.

Your static files are located in      boo**t**strap

But, in your html, your wrote:  {% static "**boostrap**/css/bootstrap.css" %}

There is a **T** missing.

The code below will work:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the STATIC file into your project app folder.

---> If your project Name is `myblog`. You will find another folder named `myblog` into `myblog` and you have to place your `static` folder there.

---> In setting.py you have to add:

```
  STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myblog/static'), )
```

In your production mode if you collect static , static file will be copied  in root static.

Answer (score -2):

I find this problem many times and every time problem was solved by add url into STATIC_URL i.e.

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'
```